# MySQL получить среднее значение уменьшающегося параметра за 7 дней

Tags: mysql, sql

Вообщем есть число которое я получаю по апи кроном каждый час и складываю его в базу. Оно "сгорает",  т.е уменьшается периодически. Мне нужно рассчитать среднюю скорость этого "сгорания". За промежуток мы берем последние три дня.
То есть:
Нам нужно посчитать на сколько число уменьшилось за каждый из трех дней сложить это все и  разделить на 3, например:  `(20+30+15)/3 = сред. 21.6`

Как расчитать за сегодня ясно:

```
SELECT (MAX(value) - MIN(value)) WHERE day = current_day
```

Как получить трехдневный промежуток за который нужно считать тоже ясно, можно используя тот же `Carbon` сделать `subDays(-3)`

Как составить запрос чтобы пройтись по каждому дню и выполнить первый запрос?
Пример расчета без SQL:

**Cегодня :**
min_value - 900
max_value - 950
*(уменьшилось на 50)*
**Вчера :**
min_value - 950
max_value - 990
*(уменьшилось на 40)*
**Позавчера:**
min_value - 990
max_value - 1000
*(уменьшилось на 10)*

Соответственно, что бы получить среднее значение за три дня нам нужно: `(50+40+10)/3  = 33.3`

Comment: Алгоритм плохо понятен. Приведите пример данных (оставьте для каждого дня только первое и последнее значения, и недели много - за три дня достаточно), и покажите на таких данных желаемый результат с объяснением расчёта. Принципиально - у Вас два уровня группировки, придётся первый делать в CTE (если версия сервера позволяет) или подзапросе, а второй в основном запросе.

Comment: Возможно что то вроде `select avg(X) from (select max(value)-min(value) as X from table where day between now()-interval 7 day and  now() group by date(day)) x`. Если конечно нужна всего одна цифра на выходе

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так. Огромные селекты в подзапросах - мои тестовые данные. У вас там будет просто ваша таблица и запрос станет коротким, не бойтесь :)

Работает так: объединяем таблицу с данными саму с собой. Пусть данные с поздним днём будут в алиасе `tt`, а ранние даты - в `t`. Само объединение подразумевает что день в tt идёт следом за t. А сами дни в tt только за последнюю неделю. Остаётся найти разницу между всеми парами, а потом среднее для них.

```
select group_concat(t_diff.v_diff) diffs, round(avg(t_diff.v_diff), 1) avg_diff
from (
    select tt.d tt_d, tt.v tt_v, t.d t_d, t.v t_v, tt.v - t.v v_diff
    from (
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-01', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  15 v union
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-02', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  25 v union -- +10
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  35 v union -- +10
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-04', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  50 v union -- +15
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-05', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  70 v union -- +20
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-06', '%Y-%m-%d') d, 100 v union -- +30
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-07', '%Y-%m-%d') d, 150 v union -- +50
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-08', '%Y-%m-%d') d, 230 v       -- +80
    ) t
    inner join (
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-01', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  15 v union
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-02', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  25 v union -- +10
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  35 v union -- +10
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-04', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  50 v union -- +15
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-05', '%Y-%m-%d') d,  70 v union -- +20
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-06', '%Y-%m-%d') d, 100 v union -- +30
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-07', '%Y-%m-%d') d, 150 v union -- +50
        select STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-08', '%Y-%m-%d') d, 230 v       -- +80
    ) tt on tt.d - interval 1 day = t.d
    where tt.d > STR_TO_DATE('2019-02-08', '%Y-%m-%d') - interval 7 day
) t_diff
```